# How to filter "table_2" depending on the selected entry in "table_1"?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

I'm using:

- Entity Framework v6.2.0
- SQL Server 2012

I have these tables:

- tbl_01_Groups;
- tbl_02_Students;
- tbl_03_GroupsStud;
   
  The `tbl_01_Groups` table is displayed in `dataGridView1`. One student can be in several groups.

To solve this problem, I suspect that it is necessary to build the table of relations `tbl_03_GroupsStud`.

**Question:** how to make dataGridView2 display `table_2` records that belong to the group selected in dataGridView1?

Requirements for `table_2`:

1. `table_2` should contain the following fields:

   - [tbl_02_Students].[NameStud];
   - [tbl_02_Students].[Property_1];
   - [tbl_01_Groups].[nameGroup];
   - ... other columns as needed
2. if changes are made in the `table_2` record, then these changes are displayed in the original source;
3. if an entry is added to the `table_2`, then this entry is displayed in the source;
4. `Table_2` is planned to be used in another query.

How to make the `table_2` meet the above requirements?

My code:

```
ContextDB cntxtDB;

public Frm1UC()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cntxtDB = new ContextDB();
}

private void Frm1UC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Fill_dataGridView1();
}

public void Fill_dataGridView1()
{
    try
    {
        cntxtDB.tbl_01_Groups.Load();
        bs_Grid1.DataSource = cntxtDB.tbl_01_Groups.Local.ToBindingList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs_Grid1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.Message;
        string t = ex.StackTrace;
        // throw;
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```

`tbl_01_Groups`:

[image]

`tbl_02_Students`:

[image]

`tbl_03_GroupsStud`:

[image]

`dataGridView1, dataGridView2`:

[image]

**Update_1**
Something like I managed to do with the help of queries in MSAccess:
Request `req_GroupsStud_Stud`:

```
SELECT tbl_03_GroupsStud.*, tbl_02_Students.NameStud
FROM tbl_03_GroupsStud 
INNER JOIN tbl_02_Students 
ON tbl_03_GroupsStud.id_stud = tbl_02_Students.id_stud;
```

Request `req_GroupsStud_CurGroup`:

```
SELECT req_GroupsStud_Stud.*, req_GroupsStud_Stud.id_group
FROM req_GroupsStud_Stud
WHERE (((req_GroupsStud_Stud.id_group)=[Forms]![frm_00_00_MainForm]![id_group_Frm]));
```

From the form, using the expression `[Forms]![Frm_00_00_MainForm]![Id_group_Frm]`, the parameter `[id_group_Frm]` is passed to the request.

I don’t understand how to do the same thing using the entity-framework and MS SQL Serever.

Comment: Hint: filter `GroupsStud`s by `id_group` and display their `Student`s.

Comment: @Gert Arnold I'm just starting to deal with the `entity-framework`. Could you explain your proposal in more detail.
Updated the question.